# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences  
        sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.sharedpre",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", "VJ").apply();
        String user=savedInstanceState.getString("username","");

        Log.i("username",user);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check if `savedInstanceState` is not null before trying to call get string, as it is null when this error occurs

Comment: help me i am getting this exception in many  app

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your line which causes the error like this:

```
String user;
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    user = savedInstanceState.getString("username", "");
} else {
    user = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before saving in shared preference check your `editText` is not or not then check your `savedInstanceState`

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
```